# Ubuntu 14.04 doesn't start after installation

Tags: 14.04, uefi

Couple of days ago I decided to install Ubuntu 14.04 (64 bit) on my Lenovo E530. My previous Ubuntu was 14.04 32 bit installed in Legacy mode, but I need exactly 64 bit. So I've made a liveusb, created partition via GParted and installed Ubuntu. But I can't start it because grub is suppressed by Windows Boot Manager, I can't even find Ubuntu in uefi boot list. I already tried boot-repair (http://paste.ubuntu.com/23415399/), but it didn't help. Also I tried all the tricks with mounting partition and update-grub command and all the other tricks that I've found on askubuntu.com. Does anyone have an idea how to deal with this problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem seems to be that there's no Ubuntu/GRUB entry in your EFI's NVRAM-based boot loader list. This problem is most often caused by a defective EFI. I recommend you try each of the following, in order, until one works:

1. Check for a firmware update (most manufacturers call it a "BIOS update"), apply it, and re-run Boot Repair. I don't hold out a lot of hope that this will help, but it might.
2. Reset the firmware to defaults, manually re-apply any tweaks you've made, and re-run Boot Repair. Again, this may not work, but it's worth trying.
3. If the computer is new enough, return it to the store for a refund, since the firmware is defective.
4. If you get this far, you must apply an ugly hack that involves renaming boot loader files. There's an option on the Advanced page of Boot Repair to do this, called something like "Back up and rename EFI files."
5. As a last-resort option, you could install a boot loader or boot manager on a USB drive and use it. My own [rEFInd boot manager](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/getting.html) should work for this; there's a USB flash drive image you can download and write to a small USB drive.

One more point: Your Boot Repair output indicates that it was unable to mount some partitions, including the critical [EFI System Partition (ESP).](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EFI_System_partition) There may be some one-off explanation for this, but the usual cause is the use of Fast Startup and/or Hibernation in Windows 8 or later. See [this page](http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/4189-fast-startup-turn-off-windows-10-a.html) and [this one](http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2859-hibernate-enable-disable-windows-10-a.html) to learn how to disable these features. There's a chance that you'll need to disable these features to make any of the preceding fixes work (except of course for the return-to-the-store "fix").

Comment: An "ugly hack" worked, thanks a lot! You really saved me and lots of my time and neural cells!